# Excel Javascript API: Rich text support for Chart title

Tags: javascript, excel, charts, office-js

I am looking to format the title of the chart that I am inserting using the Excel JS API. I am trying to highlight certain words of a chart title by modifying their color and making them bold etc. I understand that we can add formatting to the chart title  as a whole but I could not find any documentation to formatting individual words of the title. Is this kind of formatting supported through the Excel JS API ? This is an example of what I want to do : 
[Chart title with Rich text formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pa2Fb.png).

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported (neither in chart title, nor other places like cell font -- it's always an all-or-nothing format-setting).

You are welcome to suggest this on https://officespdev.uservoice.com/, though to be quite honest, there are probably a bunch of features we would take first, before getting to this one.

Comment: As per 2021 I'm interested in achieving this in a cell (individually formatting parts of it). Is this possible today?

Comment: @Desko27, I have left the Extensibility team some time ago. I suggest you ask a new question so that it pops up on people’s radar. All the best!